# Sublime Text 2 - Encoding UTF-8

Tags: encoding, sublime-text-2

How do I change the file encoding in Sublime Text 2?

[How do I change character encoding of a text file in OpenOffice.org writer?](https://superuser.com/questions/193312/how-do-i-change-character-encoding-of-a-text-file-in-openoffice-org-writer)

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3541

Comment: As i experiences sublime ,it have some issue with showing UTF-8 ,but it save theme just fine.

Answer (score 44):

Just go to File → "Save with encoding" and select your preferred encoding.

Comment: this will change file encoding.

Comment: @interlude water is wet

Comment: @aug I have no idea why I wrote that comment 3 years ago.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to set UTF-8 as your default encoding, you can also do this:

Preferences -> Settings - User -> Add this line of code

```
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
```

Save.

Comment: Just to make sure... "UTF-8" means "UTF-8 without BOM" right?
I assume it would be "UTF-8 BOM" or something like that otherwise

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3951#p18302) it's `"UTF-8 with BOM"` for with BOM.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct configuration:

```
{
    "Default_encoding": "UTF-8",
    "font_size": 9,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is an English speaking site so your answers should be in English.  You also do not need to put a signature in your answer as your name automatically appears below the answer. Welcome to Superuser.